# Can't solve problem with index and match in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

need help. I have this table and I can not solve it. Why is not my formula working?
I try to find the price of a ticket. For example, if row is 1 and seat is also 1, so price should be 170.

My formula is:

```
=INDEX(B11:D13,MATCH(1,INDEX((A19=F11:F13)*(B18=B15:D15),0),0))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM0sU.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are matching `A19` against string values instead of the actual integers in column `A:A`. Either way, is `=VLOOKUP($A19,$A$11:$D$13,MATCH(B$18,$B$10:$D$10)+1)` working for you?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thank you so much! I spent 2 days on this error. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Thats a lot of time, glad it helped. I've put my comment in an answer down below.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, you were matching `A19` against a bunch of string values instead of the actual integers in `A:A`. Therefor try:

```
=VLOOKUP($A19,$A$11:$D$13,MATCH(B$18,$B$10:$D$10)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Match looks for an exact match, so you first need to find the range that you need then find the position of it.  The following should work:

```
=INDEX($B$11:$D$13,MATCH(MAXIFS($A$11:$A$13,$A$11:$A$13,"<="&$A19),$A$11:$A$13,0),MATCH(MAXIFS($B$10:$D$10,$B$10:$D$10,"<="&B$18),$B$10:$D$10,0))
```